# Open CV Python- Video capture by webcam

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am using the code below, but I get a video output.avi of size 0B. How do I set/define parameters (duration of video) so as to get correct output? I intend to use the obtained video for further processing.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


#Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
w=int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH ))
h=int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT ))
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25, (w,h))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It could possibly be that you don't have the `XVID` codec installed on your system.  Do you know for sure that it's installed?

Comment: Hi, I am using DIVX and DIVX version 10.2.4 is installed in my system. I'm getting a black screen, the title being 'frame'.

Comment: If that's the case, then it has nothing to do with your codec installation.  It has everything to do with your webcam.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948013/using-webcam-with-opencv-python-shows-a-black-screen-w-waitkey